# Correct web-mode syntax-highlighting in org-mode src blocks

Tags: org-mode, web-mode, highlighting

When adding source blocks in a `org-mode` document (usually with the shortcut <s <kbd>TAB</kbd>), it usually works fine, but specifically with `web-mode`, if I edit any snippet with the special editor (<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>-<kbd>'</kbd>), it also works fine, but once I close `emacs` and reopen it again, the syntax highlight of "embedded" web-mode source snippets doesn't work correctly.

It seems that just after editing the source code with the special editor, the syntax highlight is correctly copied to the org file, but once I re-edit directly the snippet or I restart `emacs` it only highlights the javascript parts.

In my case, this piece of code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC web
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     const element = document.getElementById('root')
    </script>
  </html>
#+END_SRC
```

only has highlighted `const`, `element` and `getElementById`. Everything else is just white (even `root` has also lost his highlighting).

Of course, I have `org-src-fontify-natively` set.

Is there any solution to this?

**PD:** If it is worth to note, I'm using the `purcell`'s emacs configuration. The only personal configuration added by me that has something to do with `org-mode` or `web-mode` is:

```
(require 'web-mode)

(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Web mode personalization."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-indent-style 2)
  (setq web-mode-comment-style 2)
  (setq web-mode-style-padding 1)
  (setq web-mode-script-padding 1)
  (setq web-mode-block-padding 0)

  (setq web-mode-enable-css-colorization t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t)

  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-expanding t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-quoting t)

  (setq web-mode-enable-engine-detection t)

  (if (equal web-mode-content-type "javascript")
      (web-mode-set-content-type "jsx")
    (message "now set to: %s" web-mode-content-type)))

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'my-web-mode-hook)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
```

But I don't think my configuration has something to do with the problem because the special editor works perfectly as I said.

**PD2:** web-mode's auto-indentation or other features doesn't work either unless I open the special editor, but that's fine to me. I only need the highlighting works as expected.

Comment: use `html` in the header and not `web`

Comment: Then the javascript blocks are not fontified, and want to use the `web-mode` on the special editor, altough I know that that can be customized; but anyway, I want to have the javascript blocks fontified as well.